# Using Python to parse plain-text messages that use '/' and '//' as delimiters

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am working on the way to transform or parse elements of a plain-text file that contains multiple records that look like the following:

US/CIV/JOHN SMITH/-/-/Z/-/2018-03-25/BLUE/
159/AZ/AUDI/2015//
US/CTR/BILL STONE/5/TEXT/G/AU24/2021-06-18/
GREEN/174/CO/BENZ/2019//

These records separate elements using a forward-slash '/' and end each record using a double-slash '//'. Dashes '-' indicate a null value for that particular element.

I think it might be best to transform these records into JSON but not sure of the best way to proceed.

I haven't attempted this yet, nor have I been able to find any specific articles on it either.

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get it into a list of lists so that it could populate a table or something of the like you could do something like the following:

`parsed = [x.split('/') for x in data.split('//')]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really specify what format you would like the output to be in, but here's some python code to get you started. I tried to make it more verbose than needed to make it easier to follow if you're unused to doing this in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

DATA="US/CIV/JOHN SMITH/-/-/Z/-/2018-03-25/BLUE/ 159/AZ/AUDI/2015// US/CTR/BILL STONE/5/TEXT/G/AU24/2021-06-18/ GREEN/174/CO/BENZ/2019//"

def parse(text):
    # create a list of all the records, separated by "//"
    raw_records = text.split("//")

    records = []
    for record in raw_records:
        # if there is no data in the record, skip it
        if not record:
            continue
        # split each record into parts, separated by "/"
        records += [record.split("/")]

    # replace all values of "-" with None
    for record in records:
        for i, value in enumerate(record):
            if value == "-":
                record[i] = None
    return records

RECORDS = parse(DATA)
```

This will create a list of lists, where the data is formatted like:

```
[['US', 'CIV', 'JOHN SMITH', None, None, 'Z', None, '2018-03-25', 'BLUE', ' 159', 'AZ', 'AUDI', '2015'], 
 [' US', 'CTR', 'BILL STONE', '5', 'TEXT', 'G', 'AU24', '2021-06-18', ' GREEN', '174', 'CO', 'BENZ', '2019']]
```

If you want this in JSON format you can convert it using something like:

```
import json

RECORDS = json.dumps(parse(DATA))
```

The data will still be a list of lists though, is that what you were looking for?